# MPAndroidChart centre view on middle of chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using the MPAndroidChart library to graph live sensor data in a line graph. I'm hoping to give the data a sort of 'buffer' on the right-hand end so that new data is in the centre of the screen. I've tried to illustrate what I mean below:
[image]

Basically, I have got it so the ViewPort scrolls and shows the most recent item in the right-most end of the screen, but I would like it in the centre. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set Xaxis maximum, set visibleXrange and last move the viewport

```
double range = 5; // how many data you want to show in view port
double maxX = 100; // your highest X value

chartView.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(maxX + range/2);
chartView.setVisibleXRange(range, range);
chartView.moveViewToX(maxX);
chartView.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Perfect, thankyou @aiwiguna. The only thing I changed from your solution was the `maxX` value, as I am using RealTime data :)